# Move entries between sections

Tags: entries, sections

I have some entries that I'd like to move to a different channel, but I don't see any way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It’s currently only possible via direct manipulation of the entries in your database.

You will first need to visit your `sections` table to determine the desired **section ID**, and then the `entrytypes` table to determine the desired **entry type ID**.

Once you have those, find your entry’s row in the `entries` table, and change its `sectionId` and `typeId` columns accordingly.

**NOTE:** If either of the the old/new sections are Structures, there’s quite a bit more work involved, and your best bet will be to write some PHP code to handle the migration. See https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4467/9 for a complete example of how to do that.

Comment: nice to see it's really 'that easy'. I've wanted to do this a few times, moving around first work in a prototype, but figured it would be too much relation trouble. Cheers.

Comment: Brandon it would be nice if in the future you could ad this as a feature. Thanks.

Comment: Do y'all know if this is still the case in craft3?

Comment: @mooreds yep. Moving entries between sections is on the roadmap for 3.x though.

Comment: Any update on "moving entries between sections"? I am espially interested in moving "pages" between Structures. Alternative solutions welcome.

Comment: Can you add the steps required to delete the drafts first? Otherwise there are so many entries to update.

Comment: To find the entry in the `entries` table, search for the title in the `content` table, note down the `elementId` and search for it in the `entries` table.