# How to move entries from one channel to another

Tags: entries, channels

I have a channel that has three different entry types. The client has decided that two of those post types should be in a separate channel. This is an existing site with a few dozen entries currently in the channel, so I'm wondering if there's any easy way of splitting a channel like this that won't require me to manually set up a duplicate of the channel and then manually copy entries across, one by one.

Is there some way of duplicating a channel with all its entries, so I can then just batch delete some entries within each channel? Or is there a way (a plugin, perhaps?) of moving entries of a particular type into a new channel? ...or would it be easier to keep the existing structure and via templates and routing create the appearance of two channels on the front end? (That's the best solution I've been able to come up with so far)

I'd be very grateful for any advice / suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Currently there isn't any core functionality in Craft for duplicating/moving entries between sections. I think this has been brought up a few times before, but I'd recommend heading over to [Craft Feedback](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests) and posting up about it there!

Anyways, back to your question. I did [post something](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4433/move-entry-from-one-structure-to-another-with-parenting) similar to this at the end of last year. I haven't used this particular code in a long time, and I'm afraid I can't currently test it for you right now, but it might be worth giving a try.

It's also worth noting to take database backups before trying this in-case things start getting scary!