# Entry not saving through command line

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm trying to create a command line function, in my plugin, to import some data into entries. The problem is that the `Craft\EntriesService->saveEntry()` method seems to call the `Craft\TemplatesService->renderObjectTemplate()` method which uses the `SERVER_NAME`constant. Obviously there is no `SERVER_NAME` because the application is being run from the command line.

Is there a way to manually set this, or can this be bypassed in any other way?

I will include my stack trace here as well:

```
PHP Error[8]: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in file myproject/craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php at line 352
0 myproject/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(252): Craft\ConsoleApp->handleError()
1 myproject/craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php(352): Craft\ConsoleApp->handleError()
2 myproject/craft/app/services/ConfigService.php(420): Craft\HttpRequestService->getHostInfo()
3 myproject/craft/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php(422): Craft\ConfigService->usePathInfo()
4 myproject/craft/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php(196): _getUrl()
5 myproject/craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension.php(493): getUrl()
6 myproject/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(1276): Craft\CraftTwigExtension->getGlobals()
7 myproject/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(1200): Craft\TwigEnvironment->initGlobals()
8 myproject/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(1217): Craft\TwigEnvironment->getGlobals()
9 myproject/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(355): Craft\TwigEnvironment->mergeGlobals()
10 myproject/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(366): __TwigTemplate_5f77fd774cac1595e134b05c66db80e7998372598504ff29b7e2487f820a3d8c->display()
11 myproject/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(336): __TwigTemplate_5f77fd774cac1595e134b05c66db80e7998372598504ff29b7e2487f820a3d8c->render()
12 myproject/craft/app/services/EntriesService.php(157): Craft\TemplatesService->renderObjectTemplate()
13 myproject/craft/plugins/myplugin/services/Myproject_SomeService.php(312): Craft\EntriesService->saveEntry()
14 myproject/craft/plugins/myplugin/services/Myproject_SomeService.php(280): Craft\Myproject_SomeService->update()
15 myproject/craft/plugins/myplugin/consolecommands/ImportEmployeeCommand.php(24): Craft\Myproject_SomeService->createOrUpdate()
16 unknown(0): Craft\ImportCommand->actionImport()
17 myproject/craft/app/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(172): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
18 myproject/craft/app/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): Craft\ImportCommand->run()
19 myproject/craft/app/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): Craft\ConsoleCommandRunner->run()
20 myproject/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\ConsoleApp->processRequest()
21 myproject/craft/app/etc/console/yiic.php(81): Craft\ConsoleApp->run()
22 myproject/craft/app/etc/console/yiic(4): require_once()
```

Comment: Stupid question: is your plugin "installed?" How are you calling/bootstrapping  it? If it's a one-off import, instead of throwing the logic into a plugin, you might try what Brandon recommends [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4467/1016). (His example is moving structures but you can do whatever you want within the code block.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a multi-environment config.  From wherever your plugin is bootstrapping `yiic`, you need to manually set the [`CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT`](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants#craft-environment) PHP constant to the environment you want `yiic` to load in the config files.